# camerapreview plugin is not found by my angular js app

Tags: angularjs

So I have yet another problem with my home application. I am trying to get a live preview image directly on my html page. I am using VS Community and I linked to https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview.git to download the right repository. VS then tells me I have downloaded it. However, when I try to plug the line:

```
cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera(rect, "front", tapEnabled, dragEnabled, toBack)
```

I get back an error in my javascript which reads as follows:

```
Cannot read property 'camerapreview' of undefined
```

I am following the orders of the github post to the letter but I am still getting an error. Any help in solving this problem will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
Cannot read property 'camerapreview' of undefined
```

tells you that in this statement:

```
cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera(rect, ...
```

**cordova.plugins** is not defined - that's where you need to look.